# Create zip with directory and add files

Tags: linux, zip

By executing the following command you create a `deploy.zip` in a directory called build, adding every file in the current directory.

```
zip -r build/deploy.zip *
```

So far, so good. Now, I want to add a directory in the zip and then add all the files in the current directory.

Basically, instead of having the directory structure like this:

```
deploy.zip
--> all_files_from_current_directory
```

I need zip like this:

```
deploy.zip
--> root_dir
--> --> all_files_from_current_directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: zip add foo deploy.zip OR zip update foo deploy.zip

Comment: You just have to move up before doing the ZIP. If the directory has the wrong name, you can create a link (Unix) or temporarily rename it (Windows)